# Table Index Optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres, should I create two separate indexes for `from_date` and `to_date` or just one is fine with both columns ?

**Query:**

```
SELECT subscription_id, from_date, to_date from public.subscriptions
       where subscription_id in ('a', 'b', 'c')
       AND ((from_date >= '2018-01-01' and to_date <= '2018-01-31') OR to_date is null)
```

**Index:**

```
CREATE INDEX
ON
   “public”.“individual_subscriptions”
   (
       “from_date” ASC,
       “to_date” ASC
   )
```

Or Is there any other way I can create optimised indexes, assuming that `subscription_id` is already indexed.

Comment: PostgreSQL's [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/rangetypes.html) will be interesting for you.

Comment: An index on `subscription_id` is probably sufficient for good performance.

Comment: subscription_id is not primary key and there will be millions of rows in this table.

Comment: BTW:Your AND/OR logic looks wrong, (unless the date ranges are guaranteed to be non-overlapping)

Comment: Don't worry about logic, there is some special business use case behind that.